# Hair Particle growing near a mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

so I've been trying to make a characther from one of my favorite mangas, and I really wanted to make a cool hair for it, but I just started using blender for like 2 weeks, so I'm not that knowledgeable. I used a particle system for the moustache, and another one for the body, but the problem is that near the arms, and the armpits, the hair grows weird, I guess it doesn't have "space" to grow. Any way to fix this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: So I chose "None" in the children tab, and the hair grows like it should, but if i try to use the "Interpolated" it starts to grow weird in some parts, like the tip of the ears too. I checked the normals and they are ok.
Edit - I just cranked up the number of hairs in the "Emission" tab and using interpolated children fixed the ears, but the area near the arms is still empty, near the fingers too.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking for hours at the forums, I found a *solution*, just add more parents to the bald spots (well, they are not bald, but for some reason the hair grows inside of the mesh). It doesn't fixes the growing inside problem but, well, there are no balds spots now.
I used the Add tool in the particle edit mode.